# Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view, parameters

I have a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
   SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE Value = 2;
```

I'd like to make it more generic, it means to change 2  into a variable. I tried this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
   SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE Value = @MyVariable;
```

But MySQL doesn't allow this.

I found an ugly workaround:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMyVariable() RETURNS INTEGER DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN RETURN @MyVariable; END|
```

And then the view is:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
   SELECT Column FROM Table WHERE Value = GetMyVariable();
```

But it looks really crappy, and the usage is also crappy - I have to set the @MyVariable before each usage of the view.

Is there a solution, that I could use like this:

```
SELECT Column FROM MyView(2) WHERE (...)
```

The concrete situation is as follows:
I have a table storing information about the denied request:

```
CREATE TABLE Denial
(
    Id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(Id),
    DateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    FeatureId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (FeatureId)
            REFERENCES Feature (Id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    UserHostId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (UserHostId)
            REFERENCES UserHost (Id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    Multiplicity MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    UNIQUE INDEX DenialIndex (FeatureId, DateTime, UserHostId)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

A multiplicity is a number of identical requests recorded in the same second. I want to display a list of denials, but sometimes, when the application gets denied, it retries a couple times just to make sure. So usually, when the same user gets denial 3 times on the same feature in a couple seconds it is actually one denial. If we'd have one more resource, to fulfill this request, the next two denials would not happen. So we want to group the denials in report allowing the user to specify the timespan in which denials should be grouped. E.g. if we have denials (for user 1 on feature 1) in timestamps: 1,2,24,26,27,45 and user wants to group denials that are closer to each other than 4 sec, he should get something like this: 1 (x2), 24 (x3), 45 (x1). We can assume, that spaces between real denials are much bigger than between duplications. I solved the problem in the following way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetDenialMergingTime()
    RETURNS INTEGER UNSIGNED
    DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
    IF ISNULL(@DenialMergingTime) THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSE
        RETURN @DenialMergingTime;
    END IF;
END|

CREATE VIEW MergedDenialsViewHelper AS
    SELECT MIN(Second.DateTime) AS GroupTime,
        First.FeatureId,
        First.UserHostId,
        SUM(Second.Multiplicity) AS MultiplicitySum
    FROM Denial AS First 
        JOIN Denial AS Second 
            ON First.FeatureId = Second.FeatureId
                AND First.UserHostId = Second.UserHostId
                AND First.DateTime >= Second.DateTime
                AND First.DateTime - Second.DateTime < GetDenialMergingTime()
    GROUP BY First.DateTime, First.FeatureId, First.UserHostId, First.Licenses;

CREATE VIEW MergedDenials AS
    SELECT GroupTime, 
        FeatureId,
        UserHostId, 
        MAX(MultiplicitySum) AS MultiplicitySum
    FROM MergedDenialsViewHelper
    GROUP BY GroupTime, FeatureId, UserHostId;
```

Then to show denials from user 1 and 2 on features 3 and 4 merged every 5 seconds all you have to do is:

```
SET @DenialMergingTime := 5;
SELECT GroupTime, FeatureId, UserHostId, MultiplicitySum FROM MergedDenials WHERE UserHostId IN (1, 2) AND FeatureId IN (3, 4);
```

I use the view because in it it's easy to filter data and to use it explicitly in the jQuery grid, automatically order, limit number of records and so on.

But it's just an ugly workaround. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Actually if you create func:

```
create function p1() returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @p1;
```

and view:

```
create view h_parm as
select * from sw_hardware_big where unit_id = p1() ;
```

Then you can call a view with a parameter:

```
select s.* from (select @p1:=12 p) parm , h_parm s;
```

Comment: Wow, this is one of the most hacky things that i ever saw in SQL ;) But it's exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: Shouldn't it be NON DETERMINISTIC?

Comment: @MichaelMior The MySQL docs say: "A routine is considered “deterministic” if it always produces the same result for the same input parameters, and “not deterministic” otherwise. If neither DETERMINISTIC nor NOT DETERMINISTIC is given in the routine definition, the default is NOT DETERMINISTIC. To declare that a function is deterministic, you must specify DETERMINISTIC explicitly." - as I understand it is not only during the view execution.

Comment: @MosheElisha If the view is the only place you are using this function and you know that the function is deterministic within the view, you will get a slight performance boost from specifying `DETERMINISTIC` and it's perfectly safe to do so. I don't believe MySQL caches function results across queries.

Comment: This technique works when creating a view within a stored procedure, when the created view is dependent on a varchar passed to the stored procedure. In this case, I had to 'set @p1 = 12;' on the line before the call to create the view.

Comment: Is there any potential for problems (tenant data mixup) if several database tenants call this code concurrently?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D the derived table needs an alias. you can call it whatever you want, but you cannot omit it

Comment: The variable p1 retains its value after this, so if you use the view again without passing the parameter, it will use the prior one passed - which maybe confusing!  You can "clear" it after it's use like this: select s.* from (select p1:=12 p) pass, h_parm s, (select @p1:=-1) clear; (Assuming -1 is an invalid value for this purpose)

Comment: Seems there's no need to `s`. This is enough (as I tested): `SELECT h_parm.* FROM (SELECT @p1:=12 p) parm , h_parm;`

Comment: Hi all, I got a problem when creating a new function. My account is not SUPER, so I cannot create it. And for security, and server management company did not want to change any about security (like they said). What should I do in this case? We are using RDS.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically reset p1 (e.g. to -1) after the query? I would like to use this approach for a multi-tenant app, and use it to filter on a tenant_id column. But for that, I need to make sure that the tenant id is reset after each request, to avoid any risk of retrieving data of customer A for a query for customer B.

Comment: 11 years later, this one came handy for a last min prototype project!
Many thanks

Comment: The suggested solution for "clearing" the variable does not work:
`select s.* from (select p1:=12 p) pass, h_parm s, (select @p1:=-1) clear;`
That means that the variable is reset, but before the view query execution starts, resulting in no data being returned. What you need is `set @p1 := NULL;` as a separate statement. Or start a new session where the variable is not yet defined.

Comment: Can someone explain what the syntax of the select is actually doing?  Seems like a bit of voodoo to cross join a series of function calls with a view.

Answer (score 28):

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
   SELECT Column, Value FROM Table;


SELECT Column FROM MyView WHERE Value = 1;
```

Is the proper solution in MySQL, some other SQLs let you define Views more exactly.

Note: Unless the View is very complicated, MySQL will optimize this just fine.

Comment: In my case the WHERE part, in which I want to use parameter is in neasted select, so it's imposible to filter it from outside of the view.

Comment: Actually neasted selects are not allowed in views, but I splitted them into two views. V1 filters and aggregates data, and on top of V1 there is V2. I can't filter data from V1 outside it (in V2), becouse outside they are visible as aggregated.

Comment: Then don't use a view at all, if you need exact control build the entire query every time, or build the query inside a stored procedure. Saving as a view seems pointless.  Though if you post the queries you are trying to achieve someone might be able to suggest a different/better route.

Comment: I wanted not to do this, becouse it will make my simple question quite complex, but if you think it may be usefull, I'll try.

Comment: This format would not let you change the result set or the name of the table depending on a parameter

Comment: Fundamentally, a view behaves like a table so you can use a `WHERE` clause against any of its columns.

Comment: Actually doing so I have very different performance. Filtering the view is much slower than executing the query directly

Answer (score 5):

I previously came up with a different workaround that doesn't use stored procedures, but instead uses a parameter table and some connection_id() magic.

**EDIT (Copied up from comments)**

create a table that contains a column called `connection_id` (make it a bigint). Place columns in that table for parameters for the view. Put a primary key on the `connection_id`. replace into the parameter table and use `CONNECTION_ID()` to populate the connection_id value. In the view use a cross join to the parameter table and put `WHERE param_table.connection_id = CONNECTION_ID()`. This will cross join with only one row from the parameter table which is what you want. You can then use the other columns in the where clause for example where `orders.order_id = param_table.order_id`.