# Can a function in mysql return a resultset? If not, what are the possible alternative solutions?

Tags: mysql, function, return, resultset

I have a view from which I have to select data between 2 given dates (start date and end date).
The problem is that views in mysql can't accept arguments (as far as I know), and I need to return the result to the calling application.
In [Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql) a work around for this by initializing session variable.

My question is: Is it possible to have a function that composes the query from the given arguments and then return the resultset?

Comment: No, MySQL does not support functions returning result sets (as several other DBMS do). Your only choice is adding a WHERE to the view as suggested by mazzucci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a WHERE condition on your SELECT FROM `custom_view`, just like you with do with regular tables.

Comment: Hi mazzucci, maybe I was not clear on the part that the start date and the end date are not fixed. I mean that they have to be passed from the application itself (something like view parameters which is supported in Oracle and MsSql)

Comment: Have you you looked on Stored Procedures? Stored Procedures do have parameters and can return result sets: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html