# What is the best way to filter a multi-tenant MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, multi-tenant

In MySQL I have a single database with one schema. In Microsoft Sql Server it is recommended to use a "Tenant View Filter" so in Microsoft Sql Server this gives me exactly what I need.

```
CREATE VIEW TenantEmployees AS 
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE TenantID = SUSER_SID()
```

What is the best way to accomplish the same in MySQL? An equivalent to the "Tenant View Filter" will work if it is performs well.

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe [`CURRENT_USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) and `USER()` functions can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you suggest (that I could find in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_tvf)) has text afterwards that explains exactly what are its assumptions. In particular, it mentions that it assumes that the "owner" of a row in the `Employees` table is specified in the `TenantID` field that is populated according to the SID of the user(s) you are partitioning for.

What that means is that you can replicate the same idea whatever way you decide to implement your data as long as you have clearly defined partitions of the data and know exactly how to associate it with the table you are creating a view for.

In particular, if you configure your system so that each partition accesses the DB with its own credentials, you could use the `CURRENT_USER` or `USER` constructs of MySQL as the IDs defining your partitions and the query to create the view would be basically the same as the one suggested in MSDN replacing `SUSER_ID` with `CURRENT_USER`.

But if you use the same user to access from all the partitions, then the suggested method is irrelevant on either database server.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use your `tenantId` value to perform filtering, a table valued user defined function would be ideal, as a view normally does not accept parameters. Unfortunately, unlike many other database products [MySQL doesn't support table-valued functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163666/mysql-function-to-return-a-table). However, there are MySQL [hacks that claim to emulate parametrized views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql). These could be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky in MySQL, but it can be done:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {viewName}
    AS
        SELECT {fieldListWithoutTenantID}
        FROM {tableName}
        WHERE (id_tenant = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER( ),'@',1))
```

I wrote up a full blog post on how I converted a single-tenant MySQL application to multi-tenant in one weekend with minimal changes.  https://opensource.io/it/mysql-multi-tenant/