# mysql function to return a table

Tags: mysql

Is there any way so we can return a table from a mySQL function?

Like we do on SQL SRV?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[blablabla](
@grupo int,
@singular varchar(50), 
@plural varchar(50),
@flag_e bit,
@s_ext varchar(255)
)
RETURNS @resultado TABLE (flag_e bit, s_ext varchar(250))
AS
 BEGIN
  DECLARE
```

This is SQL SRV, if possible i want a similar code but on MySQL.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

ok

```
[dbo].[blablabla] = returns @result TABLE
```

now in another function i need to

```
...
begin
...
select * 
from dbo.blablabla(parameters)
...
end
```

this is code from SQL SRV, which i need to convert to MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, MySQL functions can only return column data types.

However, your function can insert results into a table of a known name—including a (temporary) one created within the function body; alternatively, procedures (but not functions) can generate resultsets that are sent to the client (e.g. by executing a `SELECT` statement).

Comment: and i can access to results from that temporary table from other function? what is the best way, so i can use the results on another function? thanks

Comment: @Gil: Could you provide a little more detail of what you're trying to achieve? Perhaps there's a better way...

Comment: well im converting some SQL functions to mySQL functions, the result is convert numbers to words... like 1='one' and 11='eleven'... now from this function i need a table to be selected in another function(select * from 'that temporary table')  .  is that possible? tell me if u didnt understand :/

Comment: @Gil: Perhaps you could edit your question with an example of how the two functions interact: what it is that, together, they are trying to accomplish?