# Return two results from function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create one function of 2nd degree with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION delta (a INT, b INT, c INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,5) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN POWER(b,2) - 4*a*c;

CREATE FUNCTION raiz1 (a INT, b INT, c INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,5) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN (-b - sqrt(delta)/2*a), (-b + sqrt(delta)/2*a);
```

But I get this error

How I fix it? How I do one function for this?

Thanks

Comment: You might look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163666/mysql-function-to-return-a-table  Essentially, MySQL doesn't support table functions.. But it *could* put data into a table that you retrieve.  Not sure if that's helpful or not.

Comment: Since the two functions do different things, keep them as two functions.  You will have much more flexibility that way.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question about `raiz1` an hour or two ago? I remember commenting on it, but I can't find it now -- did you delete it and ask the same question?

Comment: Yes @Barmar but appear one error for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only way in MySQL to return more than one value is to use a stored procedure.  However, a stored procedure cannot be used inside a SQL statement, so it probably does not do what you want.

Your syntax in the second function for `delta` is incorrect, because you are not passing in any arguments.

You *could* write the `raiz1()` function to take a fourth argument, specifying which value to return.  Using your original syntax (where `delta` is not called correctly):

```
CREATE FUNCTION raiz1 (a INT, b INT, c INT, isfirst int)
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,5) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN (case when isfirst = 0 then (-b - sqrt(delta)/2*a) else (-b + sqrt(delta)/2*a) end);
```

You would then call the function like this:

```
select raiz1(1, 2, 3, 0) as Root1, raiz1(1, 2, 3, 1) as Root2
```

Comment: I fix this using:

`CREATE FUNCTION raiz (a INT, b INT, c INT, isfirst int)`
`RETURNS DECIMAL(10,5) DETERMINISTIC`
`RETURN (case when isfirst = 0 then (-b - sqrt(POWER(b,2) - 4*a*c)/2*a) else (-b + sqrt(POWER(b,2) - 4*a*c)/2*a) end)`

But I'd like return the two real roots of the function.