# custom function to return multi columns

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a way to create a function that returns a query with multi rows or multi fields?
I say something like

```
SELECT getUserById(20)['name']
or
SELECT getUserById(20)->name
```

so, the function returns all fields from user, and then I can use any.

is it possible?

Comment: In MySQL, there is no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to [return a table from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163666/mysql-function-to-return-a-table) in MySQL. However, do you really need a function? Why not just select directly from the table?

```
SELECT name
FROM user
WHERE id = 20
```

If your logic is complex, you could "hide" it behind a view, like

```
CREATE VIEW get_users AS
    your_complex_logic
```

Then, select from the view:

```
SELECT name
FROM get_users
WHERE id = 20
```