# Error when creating view in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I want to create a view for this sql statement which previously works fine. But when I create this into a view, A error prompting out showing that, `"View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter."` Can anyone tell me where the error falls as I am quite new to views in MySQL. Thanks!

```
CREATE VIEW `satsschema`.`viewTimeBreak` AS 
SELECT a.EmpName, CONCAT(b.StartTime, '-', b.EndTime) AS ShiftTime, CONCAT(a.EmpTime,     '-', ADDTIME(a.EmpTime, '0 1:0:0.000000')) AS BreakTime, a.Break, 
                     a.EmployeeOnBreak, '' AS SignIn, '' AS SignOut
FROM            satsschema.employeeslot a INNER JOIN
                     satsschema.ufis b ON b.UFISID = a.UFISEmpGroup
WHERE        (a.AllocationDate = @AllocationDate) AND (a.LocationName = @LocationName)   AND (a.Break = 1)
GROUP BY a.EmpName
```

This part shows the error when I tried to create a view using the sql statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have variables like @AllocationDate and @LocationName used in the query definition of a view itself.

Instead what you can do is

```
CREATE VIEW `satsschema`.`viewTimeBreak` AS 
SELECT 
    a.EmpName, 
    CONCAT(b.StartTime, '-', b.EndTime) AS ShiftTime, CONCAT(a.EmpTime,     '-', ADDTIME(a.EmpTime, '0 1:0:0.000000')) AS BreakTime, 
    a.Break, 
    a.EmployeeOnBreak, '' AS SignIn, 
    '' AS SignOut,
    a.AllocationDate,
    a.LocationName 
FROM            
    satsschema.employeeslot a 
    INNER JOIN satsschema.ufis b 
            ON b.UFISID = a.UFISEmpGroup
```

And then put the conditions at the time of using the view

so your SELECT statement would be

```
SELECT * FROM `satsschema`.`viewTimeBreak` a 
WHERE 
(a.AllocationDate = @AllocationDate) 
AND (a.LocationName = @LocationName)   
AND (a.Break = 1)
GROUP BY a.EmpName
```

Comment: The select statement prompt a error stating that "Unknown column a.AllocationDate in where clause" Any idea about it?

Comment: Did you use my query for the view? You will note that I have added 2 columns in the view definition query for   a.AllocationDate and a.LocationName as you needed them in the where clause

Answer (score 1):

`VIEW`s **cannot have parameters** just like stored procedure and functions. This has been previously answered by SO user: **[view with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331792/491243)**.