# Use stored procedure in select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures

Consider a stored procedure which returns a table:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetLegalAnimals (IN prop VARCHAR(128))
    BEGIN
        -- Lots of fiddling with temporary tables here
        SELECT
            animal, hit_points, terrain, weight, height, girth, attack, defence, quest
        FROM
            temp_animals;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I would now like to filter the results of the returned table:

```
SELECT animal, terrain FROM GetLegalAnimals('rodent') WHERE hit_points<42;
```

The above query *doesn't run* as it is not valid MySQL syntax. Is there any way to perform such a query? I don't want to implement a separate `GetLegalAnimals_*` procedure for each of the (infinite) conditions, and I don't want to add additional parameters to the procedure as there are infinite SELECT and WHERE clause permutations.

Note that the stored procedure uses a parameter, so a view is not a suitable solution despite some [creative solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql) of the SO community.

Comment: i think what you need its a view, not a stored procedure. (or maybe a function)

Comment: As per my knowledge it is not possible to call SP in select statement. You have to use temporary table to store result of SP and select from that temporary table.

Comment: Unless your *condition* results multiple results, you can try `select .... into @_animal, ... into @_terrain, ... where somX='rodent' and hit_points < 42`. And you can read those variable from your scripting language.

Comment: @Ravinder: I'm not sure that I follow you. Could you post a link to a page that describes your method? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into views now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a whole table, you need a `VIEW`. First create the view

```
USE `yourdatabase`;
CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `GetLegalAnimals` AS
-- Lots of fiddling with temporary tables here
        SELECT
            animal, hit_points, terrain, weight, height, girth, attack, defence, quest
        FROM
            temp_animals;
;
```

Then you can query

```
SELECT animal, terrain FROM GetLegalAnimals WHERE hit_points < 42;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the stored procedure takes a parameter and **views do not support parameters**. Though some solutions for [using a parameter with a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql)have been proposed, they are all hacky!

Comment: Hi, you never used the parameter in your stored procedure that you posted?

Comment: You could just use `WHERE` with the view of course. Wouldnt that be enough?  `SELECT animal, terrain FROM GetLegalAnimals WHERE animal='rodent' AND hit_points < 42;`

Comment: Yes, the parameter is used.

Answer (score 0):

Use `view` instead of stored procedure

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
-- Lots of fiddling with temporary tables here
        SELECT
            animal, hit_points, terrain, weight, height, girth, attack, defence, quest
        FROM
            temp_animals;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the stored procedure takes a parameter and **views do not support parameters**. Though some solutions for [using a parameter with a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql)have been proposed, they are all hacky!

Comment: @dotancohen yeah view doesnot support parameter