# select complement records in date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables:

```
Table "Center":
CenterKey   CenterName
---------   -----------
Center1     CenterName1
Center2     CenterName2
Center3     CenterName3
Center4     CenterName4
Center5     CenterName5
Center6     CenterName6
Center7     CenterName7
Center8     CenterName8

Table "Log":
CenterKey   Date        Value
---------   --------    -----
Center1     6/1/2014    10
Center2     6/3/2014    20
Center1     7/2/2014    30
Center3     7/3/2014    40
Center4     7/5/2014    50
Center5     7/8/2014    60
Center6     8/3/2014    70
```

I'm interested in create a view, say "MyView", that if I specify a date range, it will return the CenterNames whose CenterKey are not in the date range.

For example, if I do

```
SELECT CenterName FROM MyView WHERE Date>='6/1/2014' AND Date <='6/30/2014'
```

I want this result:

```
CenterName 
----------
CenterName3
CenterName4
CenterName5
CenterName6
CenterName7
CenterName8
```

if I do

```
SELECT CenterName FROM MyView WHERE Date>='7/1/2014' AND Date <='7/31/2014'
```

I want this result:

```
CenterName 
----------
CenterName2
CenterName6
CenterName7
CenterName8
```

if I do

```
SELECT CenterName FROM MyView WHERE Date>='6/3/2014' AND Date <='7/5/2014'
```

I want this result:

```
CenterName5
CenterName6
CenterName7
CenterName8
```

Can someone help me create MyView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
select c.centername
from center c left outer join
     log l 
     on l.centerkey = c.centerkey
group by c.centername
having sum(l.Date >='2014-07-01' AND .Date <='2014-07-31') = 0;
```

I can't think of a way to incorporate it easily into a view with a `where` clause.

The alternative formulation doesn't really help either:

```
select c.centername
from center c 
where not exists (select 1
                  from log l
                  where l.centerkey = c.centerkey and
                        l.Date >= '2014-07-01' AND l.Date <='2014-07-31'
                 );
```

EDIT:

If you have a calendar table, you can do:

```
select c.centername, ca.dte
from calendar ca cross join
     center c left outer join
     log l 
     on l.centerkey = c.centerkey and ca.dte = l.date
where l.date is null;
```

If you put this in a view with a `where`, you will get a separate row for each date in the range when the center is available.

Comment: I don't want to hard code in the date range.  I really want a view that I can supply the date range and get the centernames.

Comment: @lessthanl0l There's a way to not hardcode the dates using a function and parameters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql and my version below at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25245486/1688441 . Checking explain you will see overhead is not large.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CenterName 
FROM Center 
WHERE CenterKey NOT IN 
(     SELECT CenterKey 
      FROM Log 
      WHERE Date>='6/1/2014' AND Date <='6/30/2014' 
)
```

Comment: It's close to what I want. I really want to create a view that I can query based on a date range that I supply to the view.  Any way this could be done? I don't want to hard code in the dates.

Comment: I'm... Not entirely sure what you want in that case. Parametrised query that gets you what you want to see looks like that (or possibly like any other answer given). However, View once created is just a table, and if you have to do a select either way, why not do it on original tables?

Comment: Basically I want to create a view that I can use with Crystal Reports to get a list of centers that didn't have a log record in the reporting period.

Comment: Ok but... What is wrong with doing a join query on two tables to get data? How is a View better? It looks completely unnecesary, and if it existed it would need to contain all the data from both Center and Log to work independently....

Comment: Thanks for helping. I need to make a Crystal Report that prompts for a date range and lists all the centers that don't have a log record in the date range. Since the date range is dynamic, I really need a view.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to join the tables:

```
SELECT Centername FROM Center AS c NATURAL JOIN Log as L WHERE Date>='6/3/2014' AND Date <='7/5/2014'
```

Answer (score 1):

### View with Parameter

**Final SQL Query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/570cb8/1):**

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT @startd:='2014-6-1', @endd:='2014-6-30') p , MyView;
```

**View with Functions:**

```
create function startd() returns DATE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @startd;
create function endd() returns DATE DETERMINISTIC NO SQL return @endd;

create view MyView as
select centername from center c where not exists
(
  select 1 from log l where l.centerkey = c.centerkey AND
  d between startd() AND endd()
);
```

**Reference**

- [Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql)