# I need to change a complex MYSQL query in to a view or views

Tags: php, mysql, view

I have a query that creates a rolling sum and subtracts that from a sum total.  I have the query working in the `SQL` window, but I need some help changing it in to a view or table that I can call from a `PHP` so I can use the results in building a graph.

This query builds the basis for a burndown report used in project management so it is very handy.
When I try to create a view out it I get multiple errors with joins and variables not being allowed in a view.  I am kind of a `mysql` newbie and I am beating my head on this one.

Here is the `SQL` query:

```
SELECT 
    taskid,
    projectid,
    esthours,
    actualhours,
    eview.SE As TotalHours,
    (@EST:=@EST - esthours) as ESTI,
    (eview.SE + @EST) as Estimated,
    (@EST2:=@EST2 - actualhours) as AC,
    (eview.SE + @EST2) as Actual
from
    tbltasks,
    eview
        JOIN
    (SELECT @EST:=0) EE
        JOIN
    (SELECT @EST2:=0) E2;
```

Here is a sample of the results.

```
taskid, projectid, esthours, actualhours, TotalHours, ESTI,Estimated, AC, Actual

'1021', '2', '4', '3', '20', '-4', '16', '-3', '17'

'1022', '2', '3', '3', '20', '-7', '13', '-6', '14'

'1023', '2', '2', '4', '20', '-9', '11', '-10', '10'
```

Comment: So you have a query and you want to produce a view out of it?

Comment: yes, I just don't get why I can't just paste it in to the view.  When I do I get errors  "ERROR 1351: View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter
SQL Statement:"

Comment: In order for this SQL to work I have to set variables to zero to begin the query.  My alternative is to do some sort of create in to a table then drop create this table every time I need to create the chart.  I am using PHPRunner to generate the chart. which i can do if I just reference a table, it doesn't seem dynamic if I am dropping and creating a table every time.

Comment: maybe it is normal to drop and create tables all the time.  I just haven't had the experience to know what is best practices.

Comment: I can almost get the task done with a procedure to drop a table `burndown` then create a table called `burndown`.  I can do this before the chart needs to call the table but again not very dynamic.  suggestions?

Comment: That's a limitation. You can't use variables or parameters for views in mysql. But there is a workaround. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql. You can implement a function that will be called instead of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks Alkis I will go through that tonight.

Comment: No problem. I hope this proves to be useful and if it does don't hesitate to give some votes to the users on that topic. Have fun.