# In django, can I set a variable in a preamble before retrieving a queryset?

Tags: mysql, django

I need to variably group data points according to a user-defined stride and I would like to minimize the amount of raw SQL in my code that is interfacing with django. The question "[Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql)", seems like a great way to create a parameterized view, but  it requires that I somehow set a variable before the main query is executed.

Thus, how would I set a parameter value in the mysql connection before any query is executed on the queryset?  If I have the model `Foo` and I do the very basic:

```
Foo.objects.all()
```

How could I inject the following as a preamble to any code that is being emitted by the django ORM to SQL compiler ?

```
set @my_param := 5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution which works for my current MySQL backend.  I believe it may depend on unspecified order of evaluation and could break in the future version changes:

```
Foo.objects.extra(where=('5 = (select @my_param := 5)',)).all()[0]
```

The SQL that django then produces is:

```
SELECT `srvr_foo`.`id` 
FROM `srvr_foo` 
WHERE (5 = (select @my_param := 5))  
LIMIT 1;
```