# Django raw sql doesn't work if the query includes a SET

Tags: mysql, sql, django

As the title suggest if i try to make a raw sql query from django and include something like:

```
SET @rank = 0;
```

And here is a sample of query that works if it is used without the SET:

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

Then the query will fail and django will return an empty tuple
PS: i am sure it is because of it because i ran a simple SELECT with the SET above and without it, without it, it worked flawlessly.

Can anyone help me? i really need to be able to use set.
(I'm using mysql for the database)

Comment: Probably you should use `SET @rank := 0;`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888735/mysql-set-user-variable-from-result-of-query) answer.

Comment: tried it like that too, same result

Comment: Can you post your query code?

Comment: modified the question to include the query, as i said even the most basic query fails if a Set is used when send via django raw query (also note that the query works with set if used from mysql workbench so it's clearly a django issue)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221356/in-django-can-i-set-a-variable-in-a-preamble-before-retrieving-a-queryset).

Comment: Try to execute queries one at a time: `SET @rank := 0;` first and then `SELECT * FROM table;`

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution as doru said:
"Try to execute queries one at a time: SET @rank := 0; first and then SELECT * FROM table; –  doru"
Apparently django stops at ";" and doesn't execute anything after that. I post this so i can mark it as answered. Thanks doru

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SET @rank:=0;")
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table;")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```