# passing parameters in a mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have created 2 views from a table .the 1st view is the main view and the 2nd view is made by using the 1st view. i want to pass parameters in the first view and get the result of it in the 2nd view.......below are my view in mysql

```
create view dealermth1_view as
      select a.glc,a.docdt,b.gln,(month(docdt)) as mth,a.qty from sale a,glmast b where a.glc=b.glc and b.flag3='N'


create view dealermth2_view as
select glc,gln,mth,qty as qty1,0000000000.000 as qty2,0000000000.000 as qty3,0000000000.000 as qty4,0000000000.000 as qty5,0000000000.000 as qty6,0000000000.000 as qty7,0000000000.000 as qty8,0000000000.000 as qty9,0000000000.000 as qty10,0000000000.000 as qty11,0000000000.000 as qty12 from dealermth1_view where mth=1
union
select glc,gln,mth,0000000000.000 as qty1,qty as qty2,0000000000.000 as qty3,0000000000.000 as qty4,0000000000.000 as qty5,0000000000.000 as qty6,0000000000.000 as qty7,0000000000.000 as qty8,0000000000.000 as qty9,0000000000.000 as qty10,0000000000.000 as qty11,0000000000.000 as qty12 from dealermth1_view where mth=2
union
select glc,gln,mth,0000000000.000 as qty1,0000000000.000 as qty2,qty as qty3,0000000000.000 as qty4,0000000000.000 as qty5,0000000000.000 as qty6,0000000000.000 as qty7,0000000000.000 as qty8,0000000000.000 as qty9,0000000000.000 as qty10,0000000000.000 as qty11,0000000000.000 as qty12 from dealermth1_view where mth=3
```

and i want to do somthing like this.....

```
select * from dealermth1_view where mth='2'
```

and in the 2nd view dealermth2_view  it must show only the records of 2 month only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I apparently need 50 rep to comment, i'll add this as an answer.

See: [Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql)