# How to make a view with 3 columns and each have different condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a view with columns A (select A condition =>10 ), B (condition =>5 ), C (select C condition =>100 ).

```
 SELECT
(SELECT A FROM Table1 WHERE A > 10) AS 'Group1',
(SELECT B FROM Table1 WHERE B > 5) AS 'Group2',
(SELECT C FROM Table1 WHERE C > 100) AS 'Group3',

FROM Table
```

This query brings the desired result but fills columns with null values too where other columns condition are not matched . How to avoid nulls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql Helps to create a view with parameter so that you can use single view and pass parameter to it with different values.

Comment: Show us what you have done to solve this simple query yourself. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) SO is **not a free coding service**

Comment: Sample data and expected result against that data would help. If you have five records with A>10 and seven records with B>5 what do you expect A be in the remaining two rows?

Comment: It should be blank but no null , when I get the values it should not return anything in remaining rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Daniel Cook's version works for you except you want empty values instead of nulls it's an easy change:

```
select      case when a > 10 then a else '' end as a,
            case when b > 5 then b else '' end as b,
            case when c > 100 then a else '' end as c
from        test
```

SQLFidde: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c167/2

Comment: This brings the values on which all the three conditions are applied but I want A with only A condtions , B with B's and so of C , And thanks for your effort

Comment: It would help if you'll post example data and expected result. It is not clear what exactly you expect as the result.

Comment: Updated the question please see now

Answer (score 1):

```
select      case when a > 10 then a else null end as a,
            case when b > 5 then b else null end as b,
            case when c > 100 then a else null end as c
from        table
```

Comment: I have updated the question please reply to that . I have got the query working but I wont to avoid nulls in your example nulls will be there . Thanks for your effort