# parameters for nested mysql views

Tags: mysql, vba

Here is a table with barcodes which belongs to different warehouses.

```
    Barcode  |  Warehouse
_____________________________
    1111111  |  A
    2222222  |  B
    1111111  |  C
    3333333  |  A
```

And here is a table with boxes containing barcodes.

```
    Barcode  |  Box
_____________________________
    1111111  |  0001
    2222222  |  0002
```

Each warehouse's available stock is its amount in the first table, plus all the amount in boxes.
Example for warehouse A:

```
 Barcode  
_________
 1111111  (from its warehouse)
 3333333  (from its warehouse)
 1111111  (from a box)
 2222222  (from a box)
```

This is a simplified example. After retrieving the total amount of barcodes, I cross it with a lot of other queries and tables to transform it into a human-readable report.

Ok,
The idea would be a server-side query. 
Every client (VBA msaccess) would retrieve the query and filter it using its warehouse code.

Warehouse A would call it like this:

select * from finalQuery where warehouse like 'A' <--- BUT it won't work, because boxes' barcodes haven't the warehouse field, thus, they would be excluded.
The "where" clause should be performed before the UNION ALL.

Would it be possible to use parameters in order to exclusively retrieve a warehouse's barcodes + all boxes' barcodes in a server-side query? Even though the user calls the last query with its code, it should push the parameter down to the first nested query.

Or any other trick? Maybe my scheme is wrong?

The problem manipulating queries in the client side, is that it becomes painstakingly SLOW, because as I said, after joining barcodes, I use the resulting query for building other queries.

Hope I explaied it clearly. It is somewhat complex to explain. I would appreciate any suggestion, trick, idea, etc

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a JOIN statement.  You can join the Barcode-Warehouse table with the Barcode-Box table using the common `Barcode` column.  This article is a great explanation: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm.

Your server side query will end up being something like this:

```
SELECT Barcode, Box, Warehouse FROM  Barcode-Warehouse LEFT JOIN Barcode-Box USING (Barcode);
```

This should result in a result set that has Barcode, Box, and Warehouse on each line.  Your users would then be able to filter that result by Warehouse and retrieve only the records that they are interested in.

Comment: That didn't work because that didn't add up barcodes.

I took a screenshot of it: http://i.imgur.com/CLBm2Ix.png

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to solve it:
[Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql)

I filter the first query by adding:

"where warehouse=function()"

When I call the final query, I add the parameter for the function as explained in the post. Easy, simple.

thank you