# SQL: How to use function returns with views

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pdo prepared statement that I want to make into a view in my database. The "problem" is that it requires a parameter.

I took inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331792/1986451), but I can't seem to get it to work proper. With the original statement I get all related articles as I am supposed to, but the below function/view example returns all articles no matter what I set @p1 as.

My original statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.articleTitle, a.articlePermalink
FROM articles a
JOIN articleKeywords ak ON a.idarticles = ak.articleId
JOIN articleKeywords ak2 ON ak.keywordId = ak2.keywordId
    AND ak2.articleId = :articleId
    AND NOT (a.idarticles = :articleId);
```

Where `:articleId`is the parameter given via PHP.

I created a function that returns an integer:

```
CREATE FUNCTION p1() RETURNS INTEGER DETERMINISTIC NO SQL RETURN @p1;
```

And my view:

```
CREATE VIEW `view_articleRelated` AS
    SELECT DISTINCT a.articleTitle, a.articlePermalink
    FROM articles a
    JOIN articleKeywords ak ON a.idarticles = ak.articleId
    JOIN articleKeywords ak2 ON ak.keywordId = ak2.keywordId
        AND ak2.articleId = p1()
        AND NOT (a.idarticles = p1());
```

And, finally, selecting from the view using `p1()`:

```
SELECT s.* FROM (SELECT @p1:=123 p) foo, view_articleRelated s;
```

[image]

Comment: It seems correct, but very hard to debug. You should try it with a simple query. If it works, then go for the complex one.

Comment: You create the view to return all records, and in the select against the view, use the WHERE clause to limit which article records are returned.

Comment: @Shaharyar I get the same non-result with a super simple view-select.

Comment: @SloanThrasher No, the conditions are in the JOINs - no need for a WHERE-clause. As I wrote, the original statement works as intended.

Comment: But it doesn't work as a view. If you create the view to select all records, then when you call the view, that's where you limit the records to a specific article ID. SELECT * FROM view_articleRelated WHERE articleId = 123

Comment: You join on  `a.id = ak.articleId` and on `ak.articleId = ak2.articleId`. So all three columns, `a.id`, `ak.articleId` and `ak2.articleId` hold the same value. But you want `ak2.articleId` to match `:articleId` and `a.id` not to match it. So the query can never return any row. Is there a typo in the query you've posted?

Comment: Also, your on clauses in the original don't make sense. You exclude that match the supplied article ID. Are you trying to get a list of articles with the same keywords as a specific article without the specified article?

Comment: Also, why join articleKeywords twice?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am using a relational table to connect articles with keywords, and the original query returns all articles with some or all keywords in common - excluded the article in question. This gives me a list of articles that are related to one article (related by keywords). It works.

Comment: @SloanThrasher But that makes no sense in relation to what the original query does.
I'm not sure I entirely understand why there would be a need for a where-clause (views work fine without those). My specific problem is in that I need to pass a parameter to the view execution (just as in the inspiration answer I linked to). Normally this isn't possible, that's why I have a need for a function - and this is the part that doesn't work.

Comment: The workaround just runs fine for me, I tested it on a fairly simple query. I am still trying to figure out what could be the issue in your case.. as you said even the simple view doesn't work for you

Comment: @Shaharyar could you show me your test?

Comment: Everything is same as yours, I just **changed the query inside the view** with a table called `post`. here it is `SELECT p.id, p.text FROM posts p WHERE p.id = p1();`

Comment: @Brian Emilius: Look at the query you have posted. How could you possible find a match where `a.id = ak.articleId = ak2.articleId = :articleId <> :articleId`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner uhm... this is odd... Actually, this worked last time I was on this project. But I do see your point. That's a different issue though, as I still cannot do the same thing, but with a simple view (as suggested by Shaharyar).

Comment: No, actually it does work - but there WAS a typo: a.id should be a.idarticles. I corrected it in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some typos and a couple of other issues in the example code in my first answer.

I created the three tables from your ERD involved in the query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`;
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `idarticles`            INT(10) UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT                  COMMENT 'Primary Key',
    `articleTitle`          VARCHAR(60)             NULL,
    `articlePermalink`      VARCHAR(60)             NULL,
    `articleBody`           TEXT                    NULL,
    `articleAuthor`         INT(10)                 NULL,
    `createdAt`             DATETIME                NULL,
    `updatedAt`             DATETIME                NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idarticles`),
    KEY `idx_articles1` (`articleTitle`)
)
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT 'List of Articles';


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articleKeywords`;
CREATE TABLE `articleKeywords` (
    `idarticleKeywords`     INT(10) UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT                  COMMENT 'Primary Key',
    `articleId`             INT(10)                 NULL,
    `keywordId`             INT(10)                 NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idarticleKeywords`),
    KEY `idx_articlekeywords1` (`articleId`),
    KEY `idx_articlekeywords2` (`keywordId`)
)
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT 'Linking table between Articles and Keywords';


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `keywords`;
CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
    `idkeywords`            INT(10) UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT                  COMMENT 'Primary Key',
    `keyword`               VARCHAR(45)             NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idkeywords`)
)
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT 'List of Keywords';
```

And then populated them with some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `keywords`
(`idkeywords`,`keyword`)
VALUES
(1,'Travel'),
(2,'Hotels'),
(3,'Boats'),
(4,'Cars'),
(5,'Trucks'),
(6,'Pack Animals');

INSERT INTO `articles`
(`idarticles`,`articleTitle`,`articlePermalink`,`articleBody`,`articleAuthor`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`)
VALUES
(1,'Article 1','http://www.123.com/1','Some text goes here for article',1,'2017/03/28 04:10:00','2017/03/28 04:10:00'),
(2,'Article 2','http://www.123.com/2','Some more text goes here for article',3,'2017/03/28 04:10:00','2017/03/28 04:10:00'),
(3,'Article 3','http://www.123.com/3','Some other text goes here for article',2,'2017/03/28 04:10:00','2017/03/28 04:10:00'),
(4,'Article 4','http://www.123.com/4','Some even more text goes here for article',1,'2017/03/28 04:10:00','2017/03/28 04:10:00');

INSERT INTO `articleKeywords`
(`idarticleKeywords`,`articleId`,`keywordId`)
VALUES
(1,1,2),
(2,1,3),
(3,2,1),
(4,2,4),
(5,3,2),
(6,3,5),
(7,4,2),
(8,4,3),
(9,2,5);
```

Then I tested the relationships between the data inserted:

```
SELECT 
    a1.`idarticles` as `baseArticleId`, 
    a2.`idarticles` as `relatedArticleId`, 
    a2.`articleTitle` as `articleTitle`,
    a2.`articlePermalink` as `articlePermalink`
FROM `articles` a1
JOIN `articleKeywords` ak1
    ON a1.`idarticles` = ak1.`articleId`
JOIN `articleKeywords` ak2
    ON ak1.`keywordId` = ak2.`keywordId`
    AND ak1.`articleId` <> ak2.`articleId`
JOIN `articles` a2
    ON a2.`idarticles` = ak2.`articleId`
    AND a2.`idarticles` <> a1.`idarticles`
GROUP BY a1.`idarticles`,a2.`idarticles`,a2.`articleTitle`,a2.`articlePermalink`;
```

Output:

```
baseArticleId relatedArticleId articleTitle     articlePermalink
1   3   Article 3   http://www.123.com/3
1   4   Article 4   http://www.123.com/4
2   3   Article 3   http://www.123.com/3
3   1   Article 1   http://www.123.com/1
3   2   Article 2   http://www.123.com/2
3   4   Article 4   http://www.123.com/4
4   1   Article 1   http://www.123.com/1
4   3   Article 3   http://www.123.com/3
```

And finally, created the view based on the sample query above:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `view_articleRelated`;

CREATE VIEW `view_articleRelated` AS
    SELECT 
        a1.`idarticles` as `baseArticleId`, 
        a2.`idarticles` as `relatedArticleId`, 
        a2.`articleTitle` as `articleTitle`,
        a2.`articlePermalink` as `articlePermalink`
    FROM `articles` a1
    JOIN `articleKeywords` ak1
        ON a1.`idarticles` = ak1.`articleId`
    JOIN `articleKeywords` ak2
        ON ak1.`keywordId` = ak2.`keywordId`
        AND ak1.`articleId` <> ak2.`articleId`
    JOIN `articles` a2
        ON a2.`idarticles` = ak2.`articleId`
        AND a2.`idarticles` <> a1.`idarticles`
    GROUP BY a1.`idarticles`,a2.`idarticles`,a2.`articleTitle`,a2.`articlePermalink`;
```

Here it is in use:

```
SELECT *
FROM `view_articleRelated`
WHERE `baseArticleId` = 1;
```

Returns articles 3 and 4.

```
SELECT *
FROM `view_articleRelated`
WHERE `baseArticleId` = 2;
```

Returns article 3.

```
SELECT *
FROM `view_articleRelated`
WHERE `baseArticleId` = 3;
```

Returns articles 1, 2 and 4.

```
SELECT *
FROM `view_articleRelated`
WHERE `baseArticleId` = 4;
```

Returns articles 1 and 3.

Comment: This solution works brilliantly AND it's pretty. Thank you @SloanThrasher.
The only thing that kind of still bugs me is that I never got my original problem solved...

Comment: Views aren't functions, and using a function inside a view won't work like you might think it would. There isn't (short of saving the value in a table) a way to "persist" a value that a view would see. That's why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Oops! Forgot to say "Thanks" for the kind words! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

@Brian Emilius, try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.idarticles as `article_id`, 
    a2.articleTitle, 
    a2.articlePermalink
FROM articles a
JOIN articleKeywords ak 
    ON a.idarticles = ak.articleId
JOIN articleKeywords ak2
    ON ak.keyword = ak2.keyword
    AND ak.articleId <> a.idarticles
JOIN articles a2
    ON a2.idarticles = ak2.articleId
    AND a2.articleId <> a.idarticles
WHERE a.idarticles = 123
GROUP BY a2.idarticles;
```

The FROM finds the reference article. The first join gets a list of keywords for that article. The second join find matching keyword records for other articles. The last join find the articles (excluding the reference article) with the same keywords.

If that works, then create the view with everything except the WHERE clause.

```
CREATE VIEW `view_articleRelated` AS
    SELECT 
        a.idarticles as `article_id`, 
        a2.articleTitle, 
        a2.articlePermalink
    FROM articles a
    JOIN articleKeywords ak 
        ON a.idarticles = ak.articleId
    JOIN articleKeywords ak2
        ON ak.keyword = ak2.keyword
        AND ak.articleId <> a.idarticles
    JOIN articles a2
        ON a2.idarticles = ak2.articleId
        AND a2.articleId <> a.idarticles
    GROUP BY a2.idarticles;
```

Then use the view like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `view_articleRelated`
WHERE `article_id` = 123;
```

Comment: You can add the WHERE clause in VIEW, no need to explicitly add them in the query.

Comment: Thanks @Shaharyar for the edits. You beat me to fixing the formatting! :-)

Comment: The where is when you select from the view unless you want the view to always return articles related to one article.

Comment: I like this solution! However it doesn't work. The idea is nice, but my table structure is different from what you suggest. I added an EER to my original post to explain.

Comment: Other than changing "keyword" to "keywordId", it should work fine based on the ERD you provided. The structure you show in your ERD is pretty much what I expected, at least for the three tables used in this query.

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for other articles that share keywords with this particular article: `:articleId`.

```
select other.articleTitle, other.articlePermalink
from articles this
join articles other on other.articleId <> this.articleId
where exists
(
  select keywordId 
  from articleKeywords
  where articleId in (this.idarticles, other.idarticles)
  group by keywordId
  having sum(articleId = this.idarticles) > 0 -- keyword occurs in :articleId
     and sum(articleId = other.idarticles) > 0 -- keyword occurs in the other article
)
where this.idarticles = :articleId;
```

A view an be created accordingly. Rather than restricting the view itself to the `articleId` we select the `articleId` along and can then apply a where clause to the query:

```
create view view_articleRelated as
select this.idarticles as articleId, other.articleTitle, other.articlePermalink
from articles this
join articles other on other.articleId <> this.articleId
where exists
(
  select keywordId 
  from articleKeywords
  where articleId in (this.idarticles, other.idarticles)
  group by keywordId
  having sum(articleId = this.idarticles) > 0 -- keyword occurs in :articleId
     and sum(articleId = other.idarticles) > 0 -- keyword occurs in the other article
);
```

The query:

```
select articleTitle, articlePermalink
from view_articleRelated
where articleId = :articleId;
```