# Suggest a workaround for dynamic date in WHERE clause of aggregate view

Tags: mysql

I have a view that aggregates and groups pay stubs whose effective dates are in the past:

```
SELECT 
        `pay_stubs`.`employee_id` AS `employee_id`,
        YEAR(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) AS `year`,
        QUARTER(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) AS `quarter`,
        ROUND(SUM(`pay_stubs`.`gross`), 2) AS `gross`
        -- more summed fields here --
    FROM
        `pay_stubs`
    WHERE
        (`pay_stubs`.`effective_date` <= CURDATE())
    GROUP BY `pay_stubs`.`employee_id`, YEAR(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) , QUARTER(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`)
    ORDER BY YEAR(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) , QUARTER(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) , `pay_stubs`.`employee_id`
```

I use this view in many ways. I query it for sets of specific employee_ids; I query it for specific years and/or quarters. I even have child views that are based on this view.

What I would love to be able to do is to pass a date to this view to use instead of CURDATE(). I could then ask for aggregate data as of a specific time. That could let me test past or future data. But since you can't pass a parameter to a view in MySQL, this view is married to the system time.

How can I achieve something like a dynamic date in the where clause of my MySQL view?

If I make this a Stored Procedure I can pass a date parameter, but then I lose the advantages of a view.

Comment: Assuming you mean that your statement begins with the words `CREATE VIEW AS...`, what are the advantages of a view? In MySQL, I think there aren't any.

Comment: [Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql#5331792)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach, IMHO, would be to just remove the `where` clause from the view completely:

```
SELECT 
    `pay_stubs`.`employee_id` AS `employee_id`,
    YEAR(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) AS `year`,
    QUARTER(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) AS `quarter`,
    ROUND(SUM(`pay_stubs`.`gross`), 2) AS `gross`
    -- more summed fields here --
FROM
    `pay_stubs`
GROUP BY `pay_stubs`.`employee_id`, YEAR(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) , QUARTER(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`)
ORDER BY YEAR(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) , QUARTER(`pay_stubs`.`effective_date`) , `pay_stubs`.`employee_id`
```

And only apply the condition when you query it, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `pay_stubs`
WHERE
    `employee_id` = 123 AND .`effective_date` <= CURDATE()
```

Comment: Interesting... But I don't think that would work with aggregate functions like SUM(). When the WHERE clause is in the query, we aggregate only those pay_stubs with effective_date that meets a condition. For example, the sum of  pay_stubs.gross would only include gross from the stubs that met the condition. But if we calculate the view without any conditions, I the aggregates would sum everything. Adding a condition to the results of the view would happen "too late" to affect aggregates like SUM().