# Compare multiple values to subquery result in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have two related tables as follows :

> **USERS**
>
> user_id <\PK>
>
> **USERACTIONS**
>
> user_action_id <\PK>
>
> user_id <\FK>
>
> user_action <\int>

Whenever user performs an action, there is a new insertion in "useractions" table. I need a query to fetch those USERACTION rows where user performed only particular set of actions say (1,2) but not (3,4).
So I have a query like -

```
select * from USERACTIONS where (1,2) in(select user_action from USERACTIONS where user_id=100) and user_id=100;
```

Problem is the above query doesn't work as supplying (1,2) expects subquery also to return two columns which is understandable. This is the error I get -

> ERROR:  subquery has too few columns

Giving a single value say (1) or (2) works perfectly. I want to know if there is any way I can use the same query and compare the subquery's result with multiple values? I prefer the same query because the case demonstrated here is just a part of a large query.

**Please note the query should not list users who performed (1,2,3,4) those who performed only (1,2) should be listed and also user_action values can be any random integer.**

Any alternate queries are welcome but would prefer changes in the same query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two `where` clauses in the outer query.  That is a syntax error.

Comment: There is one where clause in outer and one in inner query.

Comment: . . There are three `where`s in your query.

Comment: My bad. Edited now. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT USERS.user_id, USERACTIONS.user_action
FROM USERACTIONS
LEFT JOIN USERS ON USERS.user_id = USERACTIONS.user_id  where USERACTIONS.user_action in (1,2);
```

Comment: you could add ` and USERACTIONS.user_id=100` to the where-clause to filter for this user_id

Comment: As I mentioned specifically, I want the query to return useractions where user performed only (1,2) not (1,2,3,4). Your query would return those who performed (1,2,3,4) also.

Comment: i don't know your data, but then the where-clause might be: `USERACTIONS.user_action_id in (1,2)`

Comment: Also mentioned that my user_action_id could be random integer values :)

Answer (score 1):

This Works for your query.

You add the numbers to the in Clause

```
SELECT a.user_id
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
from 
 USERACTIONS 
 WHERE user_action 
               IN (1,2)) a 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
from 
 USERACTIONS 
 WHERE user_action 
              NOT  IN (1,2)) b 
ON a.user_id <> b.user_id                  
;
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE USERACTIONS (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
>                             , PRIMARY KEY(id)
>                             , user_action INT
>                             , user_id INT
>                             
>                             );
>                             
>                             INSERT USERACTIONS VALUES (NULL,1,100),(NULL,2,100),(NULL,3,100), (NULL,1,101),(NULL,2,101);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT a.user_id
> FROM
> (SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
> from 
>  USERACTIONS 
>  WHERE user_action 
>                IN (1,2)) a 
> INNER JOIN
> (SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
> from 
>  USERACTIONS 
>  WHERE user_action 
>               NOT  IN (1,2)) b 
> ON a.user_id <> b.user_id
>                
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> | user_id |
> | ------: |
> |     101 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=131ba9acad3eb1cdb9491c46b251d121)*

Comment: This works, but in my original data, I already have a lot of subqueries/joins and I do not want to make it more complicated. That is why I would prefer my query(mentioned above) maybe with a tweak or possibly a query with less joins/subqueries. I will upvote ur answer but not accept it as a final. Thanks for your suggestion though. :)

Comment: you can try a view with parameters https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331792/5193536 but as the necessity increase the query will stedily grow

Answer (score 0):

I see typical SO answers that aren't answering OP's question, but rather trying to steer them in a different direction. I know this is old, but if anyone stumbles upon this, I believe this will be more helpful.

I too have a large, enterprise solution where the WHERE check is MUCH more performant in a subquery than using a JOIN.

You can set a variable in your WHERE clause and use it afterwards. I am currently trying to find a better way to do this without setting a variable, but something like this works:

```
SELECT * FROM USERACTIONS
WHERE 
    ( @useraction = 
    (select user_action from USERACTIONS where user_id=100 LIMIT 1)
    = 1
    OR @useraction = 2)
AND user_id=100;
```

What you are doing is creating a variable in your WHERE clause, setting that variable, then using it later. This is encapsulated, so it can match either one of the conditions.