# What is the best way to do multi-tenant with node/express/mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, view, orm, multi-tenant

I would like to make a SaaS application, with a multi-tenant server in this way:

- 1 database for all customers
- 1 node/express server for all customers
- separate the customers data by using a `tenant_id` field in all relevant tables

Having read various discussions/forums/articles, I think I only have 2 options:

1. find some kind of ORM which makes sure there always is a `tenant_id=XXX` `WHERE` clause in all my requests, with no risk to forget it.
2. find some way to use a MySQL `view` for each `table`, which does this filtering.

However, I have issues for both options...

1. I have tried `Sequelize`, and face issues with complex queries which behave badly. I have also looked at `Objection.js` and `Knex`, but I could not determine whether they were able to systematically add a `WHERE` clause to filter on the `tenant_id`.
2. I would like to find a way to give a tenant parameter when requesting the views, but it does not seem to be possible, except with global MySQL variables. So I think that things could get bugged if 2 requests for 2 different customers happen at the same time. Another option would be to create a view for each table AND for each customer, but I find this pretty heavy, and hard to maintain. Especially, if I need to add a field to a table, then I will have to rebuild all the views linked to this table. Also, I don't know how to keep 100 database connections live in the server, if there are 100 customer sessions opened at the same time (is it a good practice to do that?)

Could you please help me with recommendations and/or tools?

And by the way, what I am also trying to achieve is version-control my MySQL database, just like for my JavaScript code, but I could not find something great so far, so as it might be linked to some ORM features, please feel free to let me know as well! My main goal behind this, is to make sure I modify the production database exactly as the development database (and don't forget to add a field in production, for instance).

Edit: the solution given in [Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql) is not working here, because the `p1` variable keeps its value afterwards. So I should think of unsetting it after each query, but the risk is strong that I forget. And if I forget, the consequence would be even worst than doing nothing: one customer would see the data of another customer.

Comment: Every multiuser web site in the world uses some variant of your tenant i'd

Answer (score 3):

The term you are looking for is called "query scopes" and almost all ORMs including sequelize.js offer this functionality.

To you scope in your SAAS application, you just need to add a defaultScope object to each of the models that need it and you are done. e.g.

```js
class Customer extends Model {}
Project.init({
  // Attributes
  }, {
  defaultScope: {
    where: {
      tenant_id: XXX
    }
  },
// ...
})
```

The default scope will always be applied to your query. For instance. CustomerRepo.findAll() will emit the following SQL query

```js
SELECT * from customer WHERE tenant_id = XXX
```

You can find more info in the [sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Every multiuser web site in the world uses some variant of your tenant id. There's no magic to prevent users accessing one another's data by mistake.

You simply need tenant id columns on your tables, and you need to write your code to use them.

A strategy for testing and validating: Reserve some id values, and populate your tables with fake data rows with those reserved values. Then put assertions in your data access code that will make your programs complain loudly if they ever run across those reserved values. Don't just reserve values 0 and 1.

If you're really paranoid, you can require the use of stored procedures for all database access, and give them all tenant id parameters. But, debugging stored procedures in MySql is a notorious pain in the xxx neck, so that's a costly kind of paranoia.

The trouble with source code control for DBMS definitions is this: you'll create your production tables just once. They may last for multiple decades. And recreating them from scratch by mistake would shut you down while you restored backups.

**pro tip** figure out how you'll handle time zones before you start putting data in your tables. I'm stuck with data where all the times are in US Eastern. If they were in UTC life would be easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your help! The risk I want to cover is that MYSELF as a developer forgets to add the tenant_id=XXX clause among the various WHERE conditions, in some of the many queries in the server code.

Comment: Right. Welcome to the SaaS world. Pain in the xxx neck, it is, to keep customers separated from each other.