# How in mysql 8 to make view with parameters?

Tags: mysql

I need to make view with parameters in mysql (8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)

I found topic(13 years ago) at [Can I create view with parameter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql)

and when I try to make in similar way with 2 functions :

```
create
    definer = lardev@localhost function f_pInt() returns int deterministic no sql
    return @f_pInt;
```

and

```
create
    definer = lardev@localhost function f_pStatus() returns varchar(1) deterministic no sql
    return @f_pStatus;
```

I create view :

```
create view v_getTasksOfUser as
  select tasks.* from tasks, task_user where task_user.task_id = tasks.id and task_user.user_id = f_pInt() and tasks.status = f_pStatus();
```

But running request :

```
select TU.* from (select @f_pInt:=10 param) param , (select @f_pStatus:='D' status) status , v_getTasksOfUser as TU;
```

I got a lot of warnings like :

```
Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.
```

and I have data retrieved, but seems filters are not applied.

Which way is correct ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The view only returns task.*  don't you want task_user.* also?

Comment: I do get data filtered and returned https://dbfiddle.uk/ZD-AO-Cp - please add sample data and expected outcome as text

Comment: I added some data and looks  your example works ok. Can My local server and this  service have different server options and that key of the different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this can be done, as shown in the old topic, would not recommended it.

- Firstly, setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will not work in future releases.
- Secondly, it adds extra overhead.
- Thirdly, it makes your code overly complex.

You can use a normal view instead:

```
create view v_getTasksOfUser 
as
select tasks.* 
from tasks t
  join task_user tu on t.id=tu.task_id
;
```

and query it:

```
select * 
from v_getTasksOfUser
where user_id = <USER_ID> and status=<status>;
```

or if you want to use parameters, use a stored procedure instead:

```
create procedure sp_tasks_of_user( 
in_user_id int,
in_status char(1)
begin

select tasks.* 
from tasks t
  join task_user tu on t.id=tu.task_id
where tu.user_id = in_user_id and t.status=in_status;

end
```

and use the procedure in your code:

```
call sp_tasks_of_user(10, 'D');
```

The direct query and the stored procedure may be better optimized compared to the view.

Comment: thank you! What are <USER_ID> and <status> in your example? View parameters ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo They are the parameters you pass to the query (10 and D in your example)

Comment: Do you mean : parameters you pass to the query - that is not about  parameters in view ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo Yes, those are the parameters you pass to the query. A view is a virtual table that functions similarly to a regular table. It consists of columns that you can utilize for searching and limiting results. A view definition does not have parameters.